# Jquery, highchart: render plot on button click, roll backs

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to populate a chart with button click.

```
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hello').click(function() {

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
     },

series: [{
    data: [29.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]         
}] //series
}); //chart




chart.series[0].setData([29.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]);
//return false;
});; //button click

}); //doc ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>generate table and plot</h3>


<form id="helloform">
<table border=1>
<tr><td>probability, p: </td><td><input type=text name=p size=5></td></tr>


<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><button id="hello">populate table</button></td></tr>


<tr>
<td colspan=2 align=center><input type=reset></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>


</html>
```

For some reason, after the click , the plot renders, and disappears. I am thinking it may be because of .ready function and I tried load function instead of ready and nothing happens.Any help.

By the way I am new to jQuery and even javascript

Thanks

Ananta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form and the button submits the form. -> Pageload

Change the first lines of your click function and it will work

```
$('#hello').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...
```

fiddle with fix:  http://jsfiddle.net/wH3FA/

Comment: Thanks, that is it. researched for more than an hour..should have submitted here..

Comment: I am back for help again, I am trying to add this on joomla website. The highcharts plot works ok for those without click action, but for this it does not work. By the way I had to add `(function($){..` before `$(document).ready` ...what may be the solution

Comment: add a new problem as a new question.   adding `(function($){` around `(document).ready` is pointless - id does the same thing http://api.jquery.com/ready/   so by doing both, the inner will be executed  immediately.

Comment: Hmm..but It worked OK when I had `(function($)` and ended with `;)(jQuery`. Thanks